# Jquery expand one row at a time

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have some table rows that are expandable but I don't know how to make it so when one row expands, all of the others collapse.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.expandable').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is('.expandable')) {
            return false;
        }
        $(this).toggle(350);
    });
  });
  $('.expandable').nextAll('tr').each(function() {
    if (!($(this).is('.expandable'))) $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="expandable">
```

Comment: Please provide proper `HTML` and `CSS` required to reproduce this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a hiding functionality to cour `click()` function like this:

```
$('.expandable').click(function() {
    $('.expandable').not(this).nextAll('tr').hide();
    $(this).nextAll('tr').toggle();
});
```

The first row hides all `<tr>` while the second row shows the selected ones.

Comment: But now when I click the button a second time, the row doesn't collapse: http://www.emich.edu/residencelife/staging/staff-1-1-1.php

Comment: I updated my solution: `not(this)` excludes the currently clicked element from the selector results and enables the use of `toggle()` instead of `show()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just collapse all the other rows with the same class:

```
$('.expandable').click(function() {
    $(".expandable").slideUp();
    $(this).slideDown();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This gives me a good idea of what to do but I am not sure where to implement the code you supplied.

Comment: @AnthonyKaake -- Replace your current `.expandable` click function with this one.